# searching sequenceof strings in a list

Tags: python-2.7

i have a list containing some raw strings in alist i need to check a sequence of strings in that list .

```
mylist = ['nfiuehfehi','data1','vrnrovorj','nroivrnov','nogiogowi','data3','enoewf',
'wnqnoqni','jeqihqofhqo','cnoeci','data4','ccnonw','fffwf','fwrfrrw']
```

i need to check the sequence

data1  --->data2 --->data3---->data4

if any one(data) is missing in the sequence search it will fail .

ex1:data1 --->data3 --->data2 --->data4
ex2 :data1 --->data2

the above two will fail because they are not in sequence and some data is missing.

How can i search it in a simpler way

```
import os
import re
mylist = ['nfiuehfehi','data1','vrnrovorj','nroivrnov','nogiogowi','data3','enoewf',
'wnqnoqni','jeqihqofhqo','cnoeci','data4','ccnonw','fffwf','fwrfrrw']
cnt=0
def check():
    global cnt
    for i in range(len(res)):
        if res[i]=='data1':
            cnt=1
            print "data1 found"
        if cnt==1 and res[i]=='data2':
             cnt=2
             print "data2 found"
        if cnt==2 and res[i]=='data3':
              cnt=3
              print "data3 found"

         if cnt==3 and res[i]=='data4':
              cnt=4
              print "sequence correct"

    if cnt==0:
       print "data1 not found"
       return                
    if cnt==1:
       print " data2 not found"
       return
    if cnt==2:
       print "data3 not found"
       return
    if cnt==3:
       print "data4 not found"
       return
```

Comment: *In a simpler way* as opposed to...?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: what are the possible data strings, is there start and end limit?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  the start of the string should be data1 and end of the string data4. in between them there may be no.of raw strings

Answer (score 1):

If you know the data strings keep a list in reverse order, pop off every time you get a match:

```
def in_order(l):
    datas = ["data4", "data3", "data2","data1"]
    st = set(datas)
    for s in l:
        # if we have a sting in out set and 
        # it is not equal to the last in our list the order is wrong
        if s in st and datas.pop() != s:
             return False
    # make sure we used all the strings               
    return not datas
```

If you want to cycle the values u can do something like:

```
def in_order_cycle(l):
    datas = ["data1", "data2", "data3","data4"]
    st, ln, i = set(datas), len(datas), 0
    for s in l:
        if s in st:
            if datas[i % ln] != s:
                return False
            i += 1
    return i >= ln
```

Output:

```
In [22]: l = ["data1","foo","data2","data3","bar","data4"]

In [23]: in_order_cycle(l)
Out[23]: True

In [24]: in_order(l)
Out[24]: True

In [25]: l = ["data1","foo","data2","data3","bar","data4","foo","data1"]

In [26]: in_order_cycle(l)
Out[26]: True

In [27]: l = ["data1","foo","data2","data3","bar","data4","foo","data1"]

In [28]: l = ["data1","foo","data2","data3","bar","data4","foo","data2"]

In [29]: in_order_cycle(l)
Out[29]: False

In [30]: l = ["data1","foo","data2","data4","bar","data3"]

In [31]: in_order(l)
Out[31]: False
```

Comment: it 's not working .False is returned every time when i pass the mylist to in _order.

Comment: @chandrakanthChandram, I added the output from running the function where you can see it is working